# How can I generate two Grub2 entries for each kernel?

Tags: linux, grub2

Due to bugs in my laptop's BIOS (or some such thing), I use the boot flag `nox2apic` when I know I need to attach an external monitor. However, when this flag is enabled, pressing some multimedia hardware buttons cause the system to hang. Until I can correctly track down these bugs and do the responsible thing, I'd like Grub2 to generate two entries per installed kernel:

- one with `nox2apic` enabled, to be used when I might attach a monitor
- one with default flags, to be used when I'm on the go

Reviewing `/etc/grub.d` suggests I could modify one of the loops in `10_linux` to emit the appropriate entries. Is this the best way? Since I'm worried that I'd have to grok most of this file, is there a quicker solution?

Answer (score 0):

It depends from distro you currently use.

If it's Debian/Ubuntu/CentOS/RHEL, I recommend you to edit file.

> /etc/default/grub

And set there value of

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Then do your favorite grub2-mkconfig as you usually.

Good luck!

Comment: Will this create two entries for each recognized kernel/what entries does this create?

Comment: @WilliBallenthin It will not.